# racket create function/lambda in let

Tags: lambda, scheme, ocaml, racket, let

I'm getting super confused by a function I'm writing in Racket. I may be too used to the `let ... in` syntax from OCaml.

```
(define/public (get-rects)
    (let wrap-edge ([(coords '()) (append coords tetramino-wh)])
        (case current-type
            [(0) (vector
                (wrap-edge (list 0 0))
                (wrap-edge (list tetramino-w 0))
                (wrap-edge (list (* 2 tetramino-w) 0))
                (wrap-edge (list (* 3 tetramino-w) 0)))])))
```

I am trying to do something along the lines of this in something like OCaml:

```
let wrap_edge = ... in
   // Create a vector using wrap-edge
```

I can't wrap my head around what the best way to do this is. I know it would be easy to define wrap-edge as a sibling but if I wanted to to a "let in" kind of thing, define is not the right choice... Though I may just be making this arbitrarily harder on myself. Should it be something more like:

```
(let ([wrap-edge (lambda (coords) (append coords tetramino-wh))]))
```

Is this the only option? It just seems so bloated to do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something like this, it's probably more idiomatic in Racket to just use `define`. You can declare a function within your existing function, then use it as normal.

```
(define/public (get-rects)
  (define (wrap-edge coords)
    (append coords tetramino-wh))
  (case current-type
    [(0) (vector
          (wrap-edge (list 0 0))
          (wrap-edge (list tetramino-w 0))
          (wrap-edge (list (* 2 tetramino-w) 0))
          (wrap-edge (list (* 3 tetramino-w) 0)))]))
```

See also the suggestion about `let` vs `define` in the [Racket Style Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html#%28part._.Definitions%29).

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the style guide reference too!